# VLOOKUP - multiple returns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to pull the country codes from sheet 1 (image 1) to sheet 2 (image 2).

I understand how to do a simple vlookup =VLOOKUP(SF!A11,SF!A:B,2,FALSE). However, I don't want to have to do it 68 more times. Is there a way to do the whole process in one function?

I guess it could be done by somehow matching the country names and feed in the country codes by name match?

**Images below.**

Rookie post - TIA.

[image: Image 1] [image: Image 2]

Comment: What are the two sheets called?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to do the same for each of the other countries in the right-hand table as you have for Argentina. If so, just drag the formula down and it'll change the cell address for each one.

Comment: @Jordan Sheet 1: "SF" Sheet 2:"JJ"

Comment: Enter the formula in the first cell and double click the bottom-right corner of the cell to auto-fill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in cell `C2` in your 'JJ' sheet and copy down:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,SF!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

You only needed to change the cell you were referring to from `A11` in the 'SJ' worksheet to `A2` in the 'JJ' worksheet.